# Getting longitude and latitude values faster

Tags: android, geolocation

I am developing an application in android and I want to get the latitude and longitude of the android mobile. My code for getting latitude and longitude is giving values after some time. And sometimes, it doesn't give values at all. Can anyone help me what can be done!

Comment: share your relevant code and show us what you have tried :)

Comment: If you are using GPS to get latitude and longitude, It would probably take time. What are your other parameters, how about accuracy? If you are not very concerned about accuracy, you can use other methods to get the latitude and longitude.

Comment: This is the code I am using now


LocationManager locManager;
        
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0 ,0 , locationListener);
        Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location != null)                                
        {
        String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
         v1.setText(lat);
      
         String longi = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
         v2.setText(longi);

Comment: And yes, I dont need accuracy. I just want it to come fast. What is the other method of doing so

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code  for getting te current location. make sure you give all the permissions

```
Location Manager location =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if(location!=null) 
{
 latitude = location.getLatitude();
 longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One quicker way would be to get the last known location `getLastKnownLocation()`
and check if the time of this location is not far  `location.getTime()`. Or use it until you get the real location.

Another tip is to use both GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER so your code will be like this :

```
    LocationManager locManager; 
    locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
/*call both providers , the quickest one will call the listener and in the listener you remove the locationUpdates*/
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0 ,0 , locationListener); 
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0 ,0 , locationListener);


    Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 
    /*check both providers even for lastKnownLocation*/
    if (location == null)
    {
     location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); 
    }

    if(location != null) { 

    String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()); 
    v1.setText(lat); 
    String longi = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()); 
    v2.setText(longi); 
    }
```

this is a simple example, a more elaborate solution would compare the newest `lastKnownLocation` between providers.

Comment: The first half should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please used last know location from your location service provider if you not get latest because

- When your application is not running at that time some other application used location manager to get current location.
- then once you start your application with location manager,what happen location manager basically take some time to prepare to send current location so at that time you have to get last know location from location provider,for that you have to design service in such way.
  once the location manager is stable then used those location.

this is best way.

Thank you 
Bhavdip