# Get continuous Lat and Long in Service Class?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

Hello i have made one service class where i want to fetch continuous location( latitude and Longitude). 
What exactly i want to do is :
I have activity say A and B.

1.I call my Service Class from Acitivity A

`Intent mIntent=new Intent(A.this, OverlayService.class);
startService(mIntent);`

2.In Service i want to get continuous latitude and Longitude and store in Local dB. This is my service.

```
   public class OverlayService extends Service implements LocationListener {


    Location location; // location
    double previousLat,previousLong;
    private static LocationManager _locationManager;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    private String allocationId, vehicleNumber;
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 5; // 5 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 30; // 1 minute

    public synchronized static LocationManager getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (_locationManager == null)
        {
            _locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return _locationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("OverlayService", "Service Started");
        _locationManager=getInstance(this);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.backgroundimage);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(200, 400, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        //Drag events can be handled here
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(OverlayService.this, A.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.x = initialX
                                + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY
                                + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
}
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("OverlayService","Inside on Destroy");
        if (chatHead != null) 
windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long: " + location.getLongitude() + ", Lat: " + location.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        double currentLat=latitude,currentLong=longitude;
        if(currentLat!=0&&currentLong!=0) {
            if(previousLat!=currentLat&&previousLong!=currentLong) {
                storeInDataBase(null, vehicleNumber, currentLat, currentLong, allocationId);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Not Saving",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
            }
            previousLat=currentLat;
            previousLong=currentLong;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    private void storeInDataBase(DeviceInfo deviceInfo, String vehicleNum, double currentLat, double currentLong, String allocationId) {
        final String KEY = "carLatLong" + allocationId;
        Constants constants=new Constants();
        if (constants.getLatLong(this, KEY) != null&&constants.getLatLong(this, KEY).trim().length()>0) {
            String data = constants.getLatLong(this, "carLatLong" + allocationId) + ":" + currentLat + "," + currentLong;
            Log.d("Constants", "Data Stored:::::::" + data);
            constants.storeLatLong(this, KEY, data);
        } else {
            String data = currentLat + "," + currentLong;
            Log.d("Constants", "Data Stored in else:::::::" + data);
            constants.storeLatLong(this, KEY, data);
        }
    }


}
```

I am getting Lat long in onLocationChanged but this gives me a bit late. Is there anything i need to change? Or suggestion ? I want lat and long continous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER** instead

```
 _locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14052143/6333971)